# ChangeDetectorRef's detectChanges doesn't trigger changedetection

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create an accordion component. There should be only one tab opened at the time. Everything works fine, until I change the `changeDetection` to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. I'm calling the `detectChanges` method, but somehow it doesn't trigger `changeDetection`.

My design of the accordion looks like this:

- `AccordionTabComponent` is the child, it knows whether the tab is opened, or closed. Through `forwardRef` he can call parents `closeOthers` method.
- `AccordionComponent` is the parent component. Through `@ContentChildren` it knows about child tabs and it manages the closing/opening behavior.
- when user opens a tab by clicking, the child calls `closeOthers` parent method with id of currently opened one. When parent component closes all opened tabs, calls the `detectChanges`. It should trigger the change-detection and update the `DOM`. But this last thing doesn't happen.

I'm not sure what causing this, maybe it's because of `<ng-content>`?

Stackblitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nnzu2v).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are trying to close other tabs using `selected` variable, you need to have a setter and `detectChanges` inside setter for the `selected` variable.

[updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvyge8)

Comment: Why would I need `detectChanges`?
I mean, if the input changes, shouldn't it be done automatically?